# MySQL Exporting Arabic/Persian Characters

Tags: mysql, excel, utf-8, phpmyadmin, export

I'm new to MySQL and i'm working on it through phpMyAdmin.
My problem is that i have imported some tables with (.sql) extension into a database with: UTF8_general_ci format and it contains some Arabic or Persian characters. However, when i export these data into an Excel file, they appear as the following:

The original value: أحمد الكمالي
The exported value: Ø£Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Â Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ…Ø§Ù„ÙŠ

I have searched and looked for this issue and tried to solve it by making the output and the server connection with the same format UTF8_general_ci. But, for some reason which i don't know, the phpMyAdmin doesn't allow me to change to the same format, it forces me to chose this: UTF8mb4_general_ci
Anyway, when i export the data, i'm making sure that the format is in UTF8 but it still appears like that.

How can i solve it or fix it?

Note: Here are some screenshots if you want to check organized by numbers.
http://www.megafileupload.com/rbt5/Screenshots.rar

Answer (score 3):

I found easier way that you can rebuild excel file with correct characters.

1. Export your data from MySQL normally in CSV format.
2. Open new Excel and go to Data tab.
3. Select "From Text".if you not find this it is under "Get External Data".
4. Select your file.
5. Change file origin to Unicode(UTF-8) and select next.("Delimited" checked by default)
6. Select Comma delimiter and press finish.
   you will see your language characters correctly.[See more](https://www.unisender.com/en/support/contact-lists/import-contact/charset-utf-8/)

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake.  Probably...

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8mb4 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8mb4`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, but it should have been that.

(utf8 and utf8mb4 work equally well for Arabic/Persian.)

Please provide more details if this explanation does not suffice.

Comment: Well, i don't what more i can give, can you specify what kind of details you want? As i read above, it's just like a comment, there is no solution. What i can do for my problem? :( @Rick James

Comment: If the Excel file is a CSV, can you get a hex dump of some of the Arabic?  I don't see any Arabic or Mojibake on that Screenshots.rar.  Can you provide it some other way?

Comment: The screenshot number 4 shows the mojibake. I have tried many different ways but the problem still, please help :( @Rick James